# SOLRNET/SOLR Logging: Need to log specific information on whether a document is added or updated

Tags: logging, solr, solrnet

I am having a big problem trying to find a logging option for our SOLR integration.

Recently I have started using SOLRNET to add documents from the database in batches as previously we were just renewing the entire index every morning.  So far this solution is working very well and is exactly what we wanted.

However, I am in need of a solution that will log every document being added and can also differentiate between an "add" or an "update". It seems posting to solr handles it in a way where "if the document exists, overwrite it; If not then add" but in the catalina logfile this operations looks identical no matter what the scenario.

My question is; Are there any logging solutions out there that can accomplish this, the current default logging options in solr that log to catalina are insufficient.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: why do you need to differentiate add and update?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It is a requirement on the project I am working on.  I guess I will have to tell my boss that its impossible :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there's no way to do that at the moment. I tried cranking up the log level (http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/logging) to no avail. I also checked the [source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/src/java/org/apache/solr/update/DirectUpdateHandler2.java?view=markup#l199), I don't see any logging or hooks there.

Answer (score 0):

The way it really works when you add a document, is:
First: delete document with id:12345
Second: add new document

For solr all documents are new ones, and maybe you can get if they are deleted or not. Anyway, I Wouldn't do this with solr, I will get this info from my primary datastore, or query first to solr to know if the document already exist.